# ntheorem and psframebox - bad box splitting

Tags: page-breaking, ntheorem, colorbox

I am having some troubles with the typesetting of boxed theorems. I use `ntheorem` to typeset theorems in a colored frame, defining them via the `\newshadedtheorem` macro. The problem is that sometimes, when the theorem is typeset at the bottom of the page, the colored box gets splitted across the pages, but the part in the second page is empty. To clarify, here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe=true, pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{\psframebox[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray, linecolor=black,framesep=3mm]}

\newshadedtheorem{theorem}[section]{Theorem}


\begin{document}
.
\vskip 17.23cm 
\begin{theorem}
    this is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I am using the geometry package just to get an idea of the page margins. Here's the result.

[image]

As you can see, the box splits, but the part of the box that goes in the second page is empty.

I thought I could prevent this by wrapping the frame in a minipage as follows:

```
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{\psframebox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray, linecolor=black, framesep=3mm]}

\theoremprework{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\theorempostwork{\end{minipage}}
\newshadedtheorem{theorem}[section]{Theorem}
```

but this prevents the splitting entirely, e.g. the following code moves the theorem entirely on the next page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe=true, pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pstricks}


\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{\psframebox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray, linecolor=black, framesep=3mm]}

\theoremprework{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}}
\theorempostwork{\end{minipage}}
\newshadedtheorem{theorem}[section]{Theorem}


\begin{document}
.

\vskip 16.6cm 
\begin{theorem}
    this is a theorem \\
    second line \\
    third line
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to retain the box splitting while, at the same time, prevent the box to be split if the second part of the box is going to be empty?